# Как дешифровать объедененные строки?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

**Задача:**

> Зашифрованный текст должен храниться в файле текстового формата вместе
>   с ключом. Перед записью в файл зашифрованного текста и ключа
>   предварительно перемешайте записываемые массивы (в получаемом массиве
>   выделяются фиксированные позиции для хранения символов ключа; для
>   корректной сборки ключа необходимо указать длину ключа в символах и
>   шаг фиксированных позиций, т.е. через сколько символов шифрованного
>   текста находятся символы ключа; указанные признаки можно записать в
>   качестве первых двух байтов файла или же в других позициях файла).

**Пример:**

 1) Перемешивать строки.

> **Входные переменные:**
>   text = "abcd" 
>  key = "12" 
>  step = 2
>
> **Выходные переменные:**
>   result = "1ab2cd"

2) Теперь мне нужно **привести перемешанную строку к исходным данным**, где заранее известна длина ключа и шаг.

> **Входные переменные:**
>   result = "1ab2cd" 
>  key.Length = 2 
>  step = 2
>   
> **Выходные переменные:**
>   text = "abcd" 
>  key = "12"

Алгоритм по перемешиванию строки(1) уже реализован:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Input
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int step, word;
            string text, key, result = string.Empty;

            Console.Write("Enter Text : ");
            text = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Key : ");
            key = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Step : ");
            step = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // MIX STRING
            word = 0;

            if (step <= text.Length)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
                {
                    result += key.Substring(i, 1);
                    for (int k = 0; k < step; k++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            result += text.Substring(word, 1);
                            word++;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (word < text.Length)
                {
                    result += text.Substring(word, (text.Length - word));
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Result Text : " + result);

            // DECIPHER STRING

            Console.WriteLine("text: " + text);
            Console.WriteLine("key: " + key);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу заставить алгоритм работать в обратную сторону.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кодировка

```
private static void Encoding()
{
    var text = "My random text";
    var key = "12345";
    var step = 3;

    if (text.Length + step < key.Length * step)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + new string('=', 20));
        Console.WriteLine($"Слишком длинный ключ/шаг");
        Console.WriteLine($"Минимальная длина текста при текущем ключе/шаге: {key.Length * step}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Текущая длина текста с учетом шага: {text.Length + step}");
        Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 20) + "\n");
        return;
    }

    var textIterator = 0;
    var keyIterator = 0;
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length + key.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % (step + 1) == 0
            && keyIterator < key.Length)
        {
            result.Append(key[keyIterator++]);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(text[textIterator++]);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Результат: {result}");
}
```

Расшифровка

```
private static void Decoding()
{
    var encodedText = "1My2 r3andom text";
    var keyLength = 3;
    var step = 2;

    if (encodedText.Length < keyLength * step)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + new string('=', 20));
        Console.WriteLine("Ключ/шаг не соответствуют максимально допустимой длине");
        Console.WriteLine($"Минимальная длина текста при текущем ключе/шаге: {keyLength * step}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Текущая длина текста: {encodedText.Length}");
        Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 20) + "\n");
        return;
    }

    var key = new StringBuilder();
    var text = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < encodedText.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % (step + 1) == 0
            && key.Length < keyLength)
        {
            key.Append(encodedText[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            text.Append(encodedText[i]);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Ключ: {key}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Текст: {text}");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно ли как-то вычислить максимально возможную длину шага?

Answer (score 1):

Написал лет сто назад , попробуй возможно подойдёт для твоих целей.

```csharp
        public string EnCrypt_Xs(string text)
        {
            string abc = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm0123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
            int lng = abc.Length;
            string result = null;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
            {
                result += abc[rnd.Next(lng)];
            }
            char[] res = result.ToCharArray();
            string ds = null;
            char[] data = text.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                ds += data[i].ToString();
                ds += res[i].ToString();
            }
            string ds1 = null;
            char[] dat = ds.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < dat.Length; i++)
            {
                ds1 += dat[i].ToString();
                ds1 += res[i].ToString();
            }
            return ds1.ToString();
        }
        public string DeCryptXs(string text)
        {
            string res = null;
            char[] data = text.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                res += data[i]; i++;
            }
            string result = null;
            char[] str = res.ToCharArray();
            for (int x = 0; x < str.Length; x++)
            {
                result += str[x]; x++;
            }
            return result;
        }
```