# Простое шифрование файла на C#

Tags: c#, winforms, криптография

У меня простая windows form. Две кнопки: одна шифрует файл любым способом, сохраняет файл и в конце расширения дописывает .crypt; другая расшифровывает.
Поиск в интернете дал только шифровку string строк. 
Помогите в реализации кода.

Comment: Шифровки строк будет достаточно

Comment: @Duoxx ну как мне зашифровать к примеру .jpeg?

Comment: Каждый файл является бинарным, делай выводы

Comment: [Посмотри тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746639/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8/746711#746711)

Answer (score 2):

Для самого простого случая можно использовать шифр XOR. Для шифрования и дешифрирования будет использоваться одна и та же кнопка button1.
Функция шифрования и дешифрования:

```
byte[] Crypt(byte[] bytes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            bytes[i] ^= 1;
        return bytes;
    }
```

Функция получения нового имени файла:

```
string GetNewFileName(string FileName)
    {
        return FileName.EndsWith(".crypt") ? FileName.Remove(FileName.LastIndexOf(".crypt")) : FileName + ".crypt";
    }
```

Пример использования в программе:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] MyFile = File.ReadAllBytes(MyFilePath);
            byte[] NewFile = Crypt(MyFile);
            string NewFileName = GetNewFileName(MyFileName);
            File.WriteAllBytes(NewFileName, NewFile);
        }
```